# Access .net dll through JNA in java

Tags: c#, java, dll, java-native-interface, jna

I have a .net 4.0 dll it has a namespace and in that namespace there is a class, I wants to access procedures inside that class using jna.

I have included jna.jar as well as platform.jar(in case) using maven,
My java code looks like this

**MyConfiguration interface**

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;

public interface MyConfiguration extends Library{
    public void callInterface();
}
```

**Accessing dll code**

```
MyConfiguration myAPI = (MyConfiguration) Native
                       .loadLibrary("dll/MyAPI.dll", MyConfiguration.class);
System.out.println("Interface Created");
System.out.println("Calling Interface");
myAPI.callInterface();
```

**but i am getting the exception--->**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'myInterface': The specified procedure could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:208)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:536)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:513)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:499)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:199)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.myInterface(Unknown Source)
    at foo.App.main(App.java:83)
```

I have checked the dll using dll decompiler tool, and it has the called function, can somebody help out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> dll using dll decompiler tool

You need to use a PE (portable executable) viewer to look for entries in the export table. ([Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com) is one.)

Most .NET DLLs don't export functions that way. When they do, it's through a mechanism called Reverse P/Invoke, which isn't supported by most Microsoft .NET language compilers. The C++/CLI language was designed for this purpose.

You might find a shorter path to success with a Java-.NET bridge product. Or, a Java-COM bridge product if the .NET DLL exposes classes as COM objects. (Use [OLE/COM Object Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx) to inspect a COM DLL.)

Also, be sure the DLL has the same bitness as your JVM process (e.g., java.exe or javaw.exe), unless you are using as an out-of-process COM object.

Comment: thanks, I already checked Dependency Walker prior to posting the question, I will update as soon as I check OLE/COM Object Viewer.